# pgfplots how to create log regression lines

Tags: pgfplots

updated: I realized my problem.

I need to plot a logarithmic regression line. I am attemping to plot a linear regression line below. How do I do this?

I found this old post that discusses the topic, but I can't really understand what everything going on in this answer. It seems like there is a .dat file associated with the post made on (Tue Nov 27, 2012 10:30 am). This post also shows the ability to input a function and then the trend line is automatically populated.

https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=22000

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {images/} }
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,bindingoffset=6mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmode=normal,
ymode=normal,
log ticks with fixed point,
%axis lines=center,
grid=both,
scale only axis=true,
%ymin=0, ymax=.0025,
%xmin=0, xmax=1,
%xtick distance=2,
legend pos=outer north east,
clip mode=individual,
%axis lines=middle,
title=Second Circuit DC Mode(Normal Graph),
ylabel=Voltage\,(V),
xlabel=Time\,(S),
%scaled ticks=true,
%enlargelimits=0.2,
%x axis line style={shorten >=-35pt, shorten <=-35pt},
%x label style={xshift=35pt},
%y axis line style={shorten >=0pt, shorten <=-35pt},
%y label style={yshift=-5pt},
]
\addplot[opacity=.7,
   only marks,
   mark=triangle*,
   red
]
table {
x y
0   10
30  7.42
60  5.57
90  4.25
120 3.25
150 2.49
180 1.92
210 1.47
240 1.14
270 0.895
300 0.696
330 0.552
360 0.433
390 0.342
420 0.276
450 0.221
480 0.181
510 0.149
540 0.124
570 0.104
600 0.089
};
\addplot [opacity=.5] table[
y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}] % compute a linear regression from the input table
{
X Y
0   5.599164502
30  5.237209957
60  4.875255411
90  4.513300866
120 4.15134632
150 3.789391775
180 3.427437229
210 3.065482684
240 2.703528139
270 2.341573593
300 1.979619048
330 1.617664502
360 1.255709957
390 0.893755411
420 0.531800866
450 0.16984632
480 -0.192108225
510 -0.554062771
540 -0.916017316
570 -1.277971861
600 -1.639926407
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\vfill
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[
xlabel=Time(S),ylabel=Voltage(V),scale only axis=true, grid=both,clip mode=individual,title=Second Circuit DC Mode(Log),]
\addplot[color=blue, only marks,
   mark=triangle*,
   red] coordinates {
(0, 10)
(30,    7.42)
(60,    5.57)
(90,    4.25)
(120,   3.25)
(150,   2.49)
(180,   1.92)
(210,   1.47)
(240,   1.14)
(270,   0.895)
(300,   0.696)
(330,   0.552)
(360,   0.433)
(390,   0.342)
(420,   0.276)
(450,   0.221)
(480,   0.181)
(510,   0.149)
(540,   0.124)
(570,   0.104)
(600,   0.089)
};
\addplot [opacity=.5] table[
y={create col/linear regression={y=Y, ymode=log}}}}] % compute a linear regression from the input table
{
X Y
0   5.599164502
30  5.237209957
60  4.875255411
90  4.513300866
120 4.15134632
150 3.789391775
180 3.427437229
210 3.065482684
240 2.703528139
270 2.341573593
300 1.979619048
330 1.617664502
360 1.255709957
390 0.893755411
420 0.531800866
450 0.16984632
480 -0.192108225
510 -0.554062771
540 -0.916017316
570 -1.277971861
600 -1.639926407
};
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**UPDATE 02.27.2022**

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
\begin{axis}[
xmode=normal,
ymode=log,
xlabel=Time(S),ylabel=Voltage(V),scale only axis=true, grid=both,clip mode=individual,title=Second Circuit DC Mode(Log),]
\addplot[color=blue, only marks,
   mark=triangle*,
   red] table{
X Y
0   10
30  7.42
60  5.57
90  4.25
120 3.25
150 2.49
180 1.92
210 1.47
240 1.14
270 0.895
300 0.696
330 0.552
360 0.433
390 0.342
420 0.276
450 0.221
480 0.181
510 0.149
540 0.124
570 0.104
600 0.089
};
\addplot [opacity=.5] table[
y={create col/linear regression={y=Y, ymode=log}}] % compute a linear regression from the input table
{
X Y
0   5.599164502
30  5.237209957
60  4.875255411
90  4.513300866
120 4.15134632
150 3.789391775
180 3.427437229
210 3.065482684
240 2.703528139
270 2.341573593
300 1.979619048
330 1.617664502
360 1.255709957
390 0.893755411
420 0.531800866
450 0.16984632
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I suspect it's because some of the input y-values are negative, and when calculating the regression one of the steps is to take the log of the input.

Comment: That did work to create the line, but this is still a linear regression line in a log plot. How do I create a log regression line?

Comment: Do you mean `y={create col/linear regression={y=Y, ymode=log}}`, i.e. add the `ymode=log`, in the first axis (and removing the negative y-values)?

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't update the trend line.

Answer (score 2):

(I'm not even sure this is what you want, so if not sorry for the misunderstanding, and I'll delete the answer.)

If I add `ymode=log` to the options for the regression, i.e. `\addplot [opacity=.5] table[y={create col/linear regression={y=Y, ymode=log}}]`, and remove the negative input values from the coordinate list, I get this:

[image]

Complete code below, after removal of the irrelevant stuff from the preamble.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xmode=normal,
ymode=normal,
log ticks with fixed point,
%axis lines=center,
grid=both,
scale only axis=true,
%ymin=0, ymax=.0025,
%xmin=0, xmax=1,
%xtick distance=2,
legend pos=outer north east,
clip mode=individual,
%axis lines=middle,
title=Second Circuit DC Mode(Normal Graph),
ylabel=Voltage\,(V),
xlabel=Time\,(S),
%scaled ticks=true,
%enlargelimits=0.2,
%x axis line style={shorten >=-35pt, shorten <=-35pt},
%x label style={xshift=35pt},
%y axis line style={shorten >=0pt, shorten <=-35pt},
%y label style={yshift=-5pt},
]
\addplot[opacity=.7,
   only marks,
   mark=triangle*,
   red
]
table {
x y
0   10
30  7.42
60  5.57
90  4.25
120 3.25
150 2.49
180 1.92
210 1.47
240 1.14
270 0.895
300 0.696
330 0.552
360 0.433
390 0.342
420 0.276
450 0.221
480 0.181
510 0.149
540 0.124
570 0.104
600 0.089
};
\addplot [opacity=.5] table[
y={create col/linear regression={y=Y, ymode=log}}] % compute a linear regression from the input table
{
X Y
0   5.599164502
30  5.237209957
60  4.875255411
90  4.513300866
120 4.15134632
150 3.789391775
180 3.427437229
210 3.065482684
240 2.703528139
270 2.341573593
300 1.979619048
330 1.617664502
360 1.255709957
390 0.893755411
420 0.531800866
450 0.16984632
%480 -0.192108225
%510 -0.554062771
%540 -0.916017316
%570 -1.277971861
%600 -1.639926407
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually I take that back. I figured out part of the issue. The negative numbers were a problem, but I was also beginning my graph with ``\begin{semilogyaxis}`` and ``\end{semilogyaxis}``. I removed this and changed it to ``\begin{axis} \end{axis}`` and then it made the log regression line.

Comment: Using this ``ymode=log`` option doesn't work when the y-axis on the graph is also ``ymode=log``. It removes the y log lines.

Comment: I put an updated post above.

Comment: @MaxB By default the `ymode` follows the mode of the axis, so in a log y-axis, specifying `ymode=log` does nothing. However, sorry for being dumb, but I still do not understand exactly what you're after. Your updated code dump doesn't help in that regard.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's me who is the dumb one : ).  I'll post a clarification later today. Thank you for looking at my question.